# Read a word char by char from string variable

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm working on a small expression parser, but got stuck:

I want to parse a word char by char into a string variable. For example, if we have 1 PLUS/MINUS 1 in a string variable, I want to get PLUS/MINUS read by characters and stored into another string variable to work with in the future. Any help would be appreciated, as I'm quite new to CPP

Comment: Is your original word a `std::string` or a `char *`?

Comment: Just a tip: You can read string to char array character by character. Then you can compare each character according to ASCII table whether is number or not then get rid of it. Ofcourse this is the basic approach. Maybe there is a good functionality under STD or boost or other libraries.

Comment: @John My original word is std::string: `std::string str = "1 PLUS 1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the formatted input capabilities of [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string orig = "1 PLUS 2";  // changed to "2" to show what goes where

    std::istringstream is(orig);    // put the string in an input stringstream

    int a, b;
    std::string word;

    is >> a >> word >> b;           // extract from the stringstream

    std::cout << a << '\n'
              << word << '\n'
              << b << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1
PLUS
2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, didn't know that this stringstream thing exists.

Comment: @K1tty You're welcome! There are all sorts of nice helper classes in the standard library :-)